# Oracle: Select two different rows from one table and select value from another table if any of the entry does not exist

Tags: oracle, join

These are the two tables. I want to select created time of TABLE1 for type = 'PENDINGTIMESTAMP' and type = 'DISTRIBUTEDTIMESTAMP' for TABLE2ID.

```
TABLE1
+------+--------+--------------------+-------------------+
|ID    |TABLE2ID|TYPE                |CREATED            |
+------+--------+--------------------+-------------------+
|156174|849118  |PENDINGTIMESTAMP    |2016-09-09 03:33:11|
|156175|849118  |DISTRIBUTEDTIMESTAMP|2016-09-09 03:33:11|
|156176|849118  |PROCESSTIME         |2016-09-09 03:33:11|
|156177|849119  |DISTRIBUTEDTIMESTAMP|2016-09-09 03:33:11|
|156178|849119  |PROCESSTIME         |2016-09-09 03:33:11|
+------+--------+--------------------+-------------------+
TABLE2
+------+-------------------+
|ID    |CREATED            |
+------+-------------------+
|849118|2016-09-09 05:00:00|
|849119|2016-09-09 06:00:00|
+------+-------------------+

If any of the entry not exist in TABLE1 for TABLE2ID then i want select created time of TABLE2.CREATED where TABLE2.ID 

Final Result would be
+--------+-------------------+-------------------+
|TABLE2ID|TIME1              |TIME2              |
+--------+-------------------+-------------------+
|849118  |2016-09-09 03:33:11|2016-09-09 03:33:01|
|849119  |2016-09-09 06:00:00|2016-09-09 03:33:01|
+--------+-------------------+-------------------+
For Highlighted entry -> Entry not exist in TABLE1 and created timestamp taken from TABLE2

TIME1 in the second row should be taken from TABLE2
```

I tried somethink like below. It is doing cartesian product and return two many rows

```
select
table2.id table2id,
case when t2.logtype = 'PENDINGTIMESTAMP' then t2.created else table2.created end as time1,
case when t1.logtype = 'NEWTIMESTAMP' then t1.created else table2.created end as time2
from
table2,
table1 t1,
table1 t2
where
table2.id(+) = t1.table2id
and table2.id(+) = t2.table2id
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

i assume now, that table2 contains every possible table2id.

so I would create 2 outer joins from table2 to table1, one for pending and one for distributed timestamps.

finally, on selecting we can use the NVL function to use the created timestamp as fallback value.

```
SELECT m.id AS table2id,
       NVL(p.created, m.created) AS time1,
       NVL(d.created, m.created) AS time2
FROM   table2 m
       LEFT OUTER JOIN table1 p ON (p.table2id = m.id AND p.type = 'PENDINGTIMESTAMP')
       LEFT OUTER JOIN table1 d ON (d.table2id = m.id AND d.type = 'DISTRIBUTEDTIMESTAMP')
```

or with Oracle outer join syntax (I'm not sure if the IS NULL is really necessary to compensate missing rows):

```
SELECT m.id AS table2id,
       NVL(p.created, m.created) AS time1,
       NVL(d.created, m.created) AS time2
FROM   table2 m,
       table1 p,
       table1 d
WHERE  m.id = p.table2id(+)
   AND p.type(+) = 'PENDINGTIMESTAMP'
   AND m.id = d.table2id(+)
   AND d.type(+) = 'DISTRIBUTEDTIMESTAMP'
```

please note: I do not have a Oracle System to test the statement at hand, and I haven't used Oracle SQL syntax for about 3 years now. So please excuse, if there are syntactical errors.

But I hope, you get the idea.

Comment: The following SQL is the Oracle version of your query. WITH 
pend AS
 (SELECT table2id, created
    FROM table1
   WHERE type = 'PENDINGTIMESTAMP'),
dist AS
 (SELECT table2id, created
    FROM table1
   WHERE type = 'DISTRIBUTEDTIMESTAMP')  
SELECT t2.id,
       NVL(p.created, t2.created) AS time1,
       NVL(d.created, t2.created) AS time2
  FROM table2 t2
       LEFT JOIN pend p ON t2.id = p.table2id
       LEFT JOIN dist d ON t2.id = d.table2id.

Comment: It is working when both 'PENDINGTIMESTAMP' and 'DISTRIBUTEDTIMESTAMP' present for a table2id.

It is not working if any of the entry not present.

Comment: which variant did you try?
note: i just changed a mistake in my second (oracle style) variant.
although in this case I find the first variant (ansi-sql) way easier to understand (the changes there, parantheses and the LEFT keywords should make no difference afair)